# get ref to child components injected from outside

Tags: reactjs

We have in our current application created react components that are to be used like dumb components by the client apps.

index.js(the entry for webpack) has the following

```
export {Container} from "./path/to/container";
...
export {ComponentN} from "./path/to/componentN";
```

We have exported it out as a node distributable. this repo also contains the container component.

We include this distributable and instantiate the components in the client app.

```
var containerComponent = React.createElement(Container,\*props*\,childControls)
var container = ReactDOM.render(containerComponent,\*the root node*\)
```

The container code is as follows

```
export class Container extends Component{
    constructor(){
        ...
    }

    getValue(){
      \*get the children and call getValue on then and return the aggregate value*\
    }

    render(){
        return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
    }
}
```

but now we want to have an interface in all these components(**getValue()**) and hence we want reference to these child components. Any control can be passed to this container as long as the component adheres to this interface.

so in client app when we do `container.getValue()` which in turn should do `getValue()` on its children.

The problem is we cannot attach the ref callback to these child components that are passed in since the ref is read only. Neither can we clone these component and add the ref callback since React.cloneElement prohibits it and preserves the original ref.

So how do we get a reference to these child components and be able to call the **getValue()** function of those child components?.

If there is a better way to this entire approach, please do suggest.